# Selenium 3 new tab in Fire Fox incognito window

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to open **two Tabs in the same window** in ***Firefox 56*** *(56.0.2)* with ***Selenium 3*** *(3.5.1)* and ***geckodriver*** *(0.19.1)* without luck. In Selenium 2 with Firefox 47 I opened it with a code similar to the above, but from those versions it doesn't work anymore. Anyone have idea what can I do?

**The code I'm using now:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile= prof.getProfile ("default");
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) ;
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setProfile(profile);
        FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        browser.get("https://www.google.com");
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/786):

> Ctrl-T is not a shortcut which is allowed to run from content. So you
>   shouldn't use it for opening a new tab. I don't see why the
>   multi-process feature should make a difference here, and why it should
>   work when you turn it off.
>
> As we are aware on bug 380637 some websites override those shortcuts.
>   There is still no appropriate fix for that available.
>
> If you want to open a new tab you can first load a HTML testcase like
>   https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/marionette/harness/marionette_harness/www/windowHandles.html
>   which can open a new tab by just clicking an element on the page.

So you could do something like this:

```
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/");
        org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor js;
        if (driver instanceof org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor) {
            js = (org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This driver does not support JavaScript!");
        }

        js.executeScript("window.open('http://www.seleniumhq.org');");
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work with that javascript. Is there any other way to skip this bug?

Comment: I found the answer in the discussion you mentioned. the line that fixed it for me was `options.addPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);`

Comment: @gilad Happy to help. If this answer helped you to solve your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Davide I was able to fix it.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProfilesIni prof = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile profile= prof.getProfile ("default");
        profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true) ;
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setProfile(profile);
        options.addPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false); // This is the new line that fixed it
        FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(options);

        browser.get("https://www.google.com");
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "t"));
    }
}
```